# Does HttpsURLConnection support IPv6?

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

I cannot connect to a IPv6 server through HttpsURLConnection, `getInputStream()` returns null when I sent a request.

I didn't find any useful information: Android developer guide said HttpURLConnection can transparent support IPv6, but didn't mention HttpsURLConnection can support IPv6 or not. Does anyone have experience about this?

**Update - 1:**

On server side I found a error log when connection failed:

```
[error] Hostname [xxxx:xxxx:x:xx::xxx] provided via SNI and 
        hostname xxxx:xxxx:x:xx::xxx provided via HTTP are different
```

To connect to same IPv6 Apache server (version 2.2.27), Apache HttpClient works without any problem, but HttpsURLConnection doesn't. So it may not be a server side issue. Does anyone see this error before when using HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: Your edit constitute a whole new question, which should be asked and tagged separately.

Comment: ok I would create another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773276/httpsurlconnection-cannot-connect-to-ipv6-server), and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Java* supports IPv6, and has done for many years. `HttpsURLConnection` supports whatever Java supports.

You might also have noticed that `HttpsURLConnection` extends `HttpURLConnection.`