# HttpsURLConnection cannot connect to IPv6 server

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

An error occurs when connecting to a `IPv6` server via `HttpsURLConnection`:

```
[error] Hostname [xxxx:xxxx:x:xx::xxx] provided via SNI and 
        hostname xxxx:xxxx:x:xx::xxx provided via HTTP are different
```

To connect to same `IPv6 Apache server(version 2.2.27)`, `Apache HttpClient` works without any problem, but `HttpsURLConnection` doesn't. So it may not be a server side issue. Does anyone see this error before when using `HttpsURLConnection`?

Comment: At least [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594604/connect-request-to-a-forward-http-proxy-over-an-ssl-connection) [people (serverfault link)](http://serverfault.com/questions/434253/hostname-and-ssl-apache-issue-on-debian) had similar problem. May be the answers for these questions will be relevant to you too.

Comment: I just face the same problem, did you already find the solution ?